# Is a second bachelors degree worth it?

Tags: graduate-school, university, undergraduate, degree, bachelor

I'm about to finish up a BA in linguistics and am looking at some interdisciplinary options for grad school (specifically in cognitive science).

I have a competitive GPA in my last two academic years, though my first year was a bit of a wash to say the least.

I was thinking that it would be a good idea to go back for a second degree for the following reasons:

1. to boost my cumulative gpa (my academic performance in first year was a pretty big blow to my cgpa)
2. to gain a better understanding of my research interests. (There are certain science courses that I haven't taken that make me feel downright incompetent without, such as first year physics and math.)

However, I'm acutely aware that I know nothing when it comes to grad school admissions, especially when it comes to interdisciplinary programs such as cognitive science. Is a second degree worth it?

Comment: This question may help: [Second bachelor degree vs Master program in USA (math/engineering)](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/20017/second-bachelor-degree-vs-master-program-in-usa-math-engineering)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have in mind a second degree in a completely different field, I think you'd be spinning your wheels.  You can probably take those physics and math courses in post-baccalaureate status; check with the institution from which you got your degree.

If you are thinking of a second bachelor's degree in a field similar to your first, go for the master's degree in that field instead.  Your freshman year GPA will probably not keep you out of most programs since you have a solid record in your final years.  Presumably you'd get good recommendations from your upper division professors.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I have the feeling that I don't necessarily need an entire new degree to make up for the deficits in my knowledge. So this route makes much sense.